# linking parameters for converting .o files to .elf

Tags: makefile, arm, cross-compiling

I have six source files and I would like to link them using the `.elf` format. I have written a makefile that converts all the source code files to .obj files.

When I attempt to link these object files using the syntax I gave in the makefile, the following errors appear:

```
gcc -c rt_look.c
Linking ARM test_rom.elf
make[1]: o: Command not found
make[1]: [test_rom.elf] Error 127 (ignored)
make[1]: Leaving directory `/c/Imperas/Demo/main/isolated_model_ert_rtw
```

I am also pasting the makefile rules:

```
all:$(OBJ) test_rom.elf 

ert_main.o:              ert_main.c isolated_model.h rtwtypes.h
             gcc -c ert_main.c
isolated_model.o:        isolated_model.c isolated_model.h isolated_model_private.h
             gcc -c isolated_model.c
isolated_model_date.o:   isolated_model_data.c isolated_model.h isolated_model_data.h
             gcc -c isolated_model_data.c
rt_look2d_normal.o:      rt_look2d_normal.c rtlibsrc.h
             gcc -c rt_look2d_normal.c
rt_nonfinite.o:          rt_nonfinite.c rt_nonfinite.h
             gcc -c rt_nonfinite.c
rt_look.o:           rt_look.c rtlibsrc.h
             gcc -c rt_look.c
syscalls.o:          syscalls.c
             gcc -c syscalls.c
test_rom.elf:        $(OBJ) 
                     $(V) echo "Linking $(CROSS) $@"
                     $(V) $(IMPERAS_LINK) -o $@ $^ $(IMPERAS_LDFLAGS) -lm

clean::
-rm -f test_rom.elf
-rm -f *.$(OBJ).o

endif
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `V` and `IMPERAS_LINK` variables are not set, or set to an empty value, so when building `test_rom.elf`, `make` runs the command

```
 -o $@ $^ $(IMPERAS_LDFLAGS) -lm
```

which attempts to run the `o` command. Since the first character in the command is `-`, `make` ignores the error.

Try replacing `"Linking $(CROSS)"` with `"Linking $(CROSS) with $(IMPERAS_LINK)"` to see if this is the case.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But the problem was much complicated than I thought. I had to also provide linker scripts since the elf code generated by this makefile has to be simulated on OVP simulator. The elf file doesnt compile because of parse error in the linker script file which I am trying to fix.